# implementing bfs without adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I was solving problems on BFS.I was able to implement BFS algo in C through adjacency list but i was stuck in this problem:
i have to tell whether it is possible to travel from the starting point of the maze to the end point of the maze.the cells contain either 0 or 1.Given the restriction that it cannot be travelled through the cells containing value 1 and movement between two cells is possible only if they share a common edge.
So how to implement BFS here directly without going for adjacency list?

Comment: How about looking at the map (2d array) for the adjacent cells instead of an adjacency list?

Comment: @Shahbaz you don't need to have the adjacency list stored explicitly to solve the problem.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, isn't that what I said?

Comment: @Shahbaz I understood the initial version of your comment in a different manner- I thought you are proposing OP to use an std::map to represent the adjacency list. I apologize as aparently this is not what you meant.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, no need to apologize. I meant exactly what you had written in your answer, the map being the 2d array containing the 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to have explicit representation of the graph as adjacency list to do BFS. From each cell `(x,y)` you know which are its 4 potential neighbours - `(x-1, y)`, `(x, y-1)`, `(x+1, y)` and `(x, y+1)`. I say `potential` because any of them may fall off the table and thus not be a neighbor. Now simply identify each vertex with a pair of integers-its coordinates and push pairs in a queue. When popping from the queue access the four possible neighbors using what I said above.

Hope this is enough to help you - I can provide full code but it is better for you to write it on your own.

Comment: yeah now i get it. but i dont know hoW to use pair in C?

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh, just get two different variables. There's your pair! But seriously, you create a `struct` putting the two variables inside it.

Comment: @Shahbaz yeah i got it.i am using stl rather

Comment: @RahulKumarSingh, `std::pair` would do then. By the way, STL is part of the C++ library (not C).